# When a StringBuilder enlarges to accommodate a larger string, can the size increase be controlled separately from the Capacity?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.7.2

When a `StringBuilder` enlarges to accommodate a larger string, can the size of the increase be controlled separately from `Capacity`?

The code below demonstrates the issue. `StringBuilder` uses the initial `Capacity` for the increment, thus doubling in size for just one extra character.

But what if I need a large initial capacity, and small size increases? For instance, `StringBuilder(16384)` would double in size to 32768. But I only need small increases like 16 or 32.

Can the increment size be changed? Instead of using `Capacity()`?

I found the comment below in the [documentation for Append()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2#system-text-stringbuilder-insert(system-int32-system-string)). Perhaps what I describe is what this refers to?

> In .NET Core and in the .NET Framework 4.0 and later versions, when
> you instantiate the StringBuilder object by calling the
> StringBuilder(Int32, Int32) constructor, both the length and the
> capacity of the StringBuilder instance can grow beyond the value of
> its MaxCapacity property. This can occur particularly when you call
> the Append(String) and AppendFormat(String, Object) methods to append
> small strings.

```
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
    Public Sub main()
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(64)
        Dim str As String
        str = StrDup(64, "x")
        sb.Append(str) '64 charcters.
        Console.WriteLine("Results:")
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-68} Capacity={1}", sb.ToString, sb.Capacity.ToString)
        sb.Append("y") 'One more.
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-68} Capacity={1}", sb.ToString, sb.Capacity.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close.")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Results:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     Capacity=64
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy    Capacity=128
Press any key to close.
```

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it to a large enough size to start with?

Comment: @GSerg ahh yes looks like it might help. I was looking for hits for VB.Net, so I was looking in the wrong place. There's a lot going on in that post; it will take me a bit to read it.

Comment: @Charlieface my example is a simplistic one to ask the question. The actual project starts with an array of StringBuilder objects like this: `Dim Fields(n) As StringBuilder`. The n= anywhere from a dozen to 900 (nine hundred), and each SB in that array could be 12 to 2000 in size. So I want to manage the sizes as much as possible.

Comment: Unless you are using a very old version of .Net you don't have to worry about StringBuilder doubling based on capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7740dbd7fdb54e87c6aec5eb7b193bc7d21b68f1/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L264) [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,7529ccd440df5320,references), setting `Capacity` manually directly changes the size of the `StringBuilder` backing field, it does not use the current `Length` as part of that.

So you can just manually set it

```vb
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(64)
sb.Append("x"c, 64) '64 charcters.
Console.WriteLine("Results:")
Console.WriteLine("{0,-68} Capacity={1}", sb.ToString, sb.Capacity.ToString)

sb.Capacity += 1
sb.Append("y") 'One more.
Console.WriteLine("{0,-68} Capacity={1}", sb.ToString, sb.Capacity.ToString)
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rJjokR)

Comment: Hmmm that's a possibility. I suppose in the end, the calculation needs to occur somewhere. So it probably doesn't matter if it's in my form class, or the StringBuilder class. Thanks for the idea.